# GeoGebra wont launch

Tags: software-installation

I installed GeoGebra via Ubuntu Update. When I try to launch it, I can see the icon in the top left corner, next to 'Activities', with its spinning wheel. However, it soon stops and nothing happens. How can I fix this?